# Automate filling a Google Form using a Google spreadsheet (with dropdown menus)

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-forms

I have a Google Form that I would like to automatically fill & submit repeatedly using information from a Google Spreadsheet. (I'm a teacher - that will be obvious soon).

The form: **bolded are the fields which I'd like to fill in, others left blank**

-**Student ID: (short answer)**

-**Academic Intervention: (dropdown box - ideal response each time is "assigned tutorial")**

-Behavior Intervention: (dropdown box)

-Check here if phone numbers don't work: (checkbox)

-**Result/Notes/Working number: (short answer)**

[Link to practice google form](https://forms.gle/Vctj5pbpXATJxYvTA)

I have a spreadsheet set up already some of this information. I saw a tutorial (sigh...YouTube) that would help with the short answers, but no clue how to set up the dropdown response. Any advice or referral to another answer somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Using FormApp [1] and SpreadsheetApp [2] methods I made the following Apps Script code which worked sending several form responses with the Spreadsheet information (Column A for student ID and Column B for notes):

```
function myFunction() {
  var existingForm = FormApp.openById('[FORM-ID]');
  var questions = existingForm.getItems();
  var IdQuestion = questions[0];
  var AIQuestion = questions[1];
  var NotesQuestion = questions[4];

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("[SPREADSHEET-ID]");
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]; 
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i = 1; i<data.length ; i++) {
    var response = existingForm.createResponse();
    response.withItemResponse(IdQuestion.asTextItem().createResponse(data[i][0]));
    response.withItemResponse(NotesQuestion.asTextItem().createResponse(data[i][1]));
    response.withItemResponse(AIQuestion.asListItem().createResponse("assigned tutorial"));
    response.submit();
  }
}
```

You need to replace both SpreasheetID and FormId in the code. The data in the spreadsheet starts from 2nd row (first row for headers).

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app

Comment: Thanks for your help! How might I find the Form ID and Spreadsheet ID?

Comment: Document URLs have this format https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[DOC-ID]/edit#gid=0